# webapp2, self.request.path change issue on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

in my GAE app i use `webapp2.RequestHandler.initialize` to do custom stuff to the request.
up to a few days ago changing `os.environ['PATH_INFO']` did influence calling self.request.path on the RequestHandler and it reflected the changed request path. 
(and this still works fine on the SDK)

now it does not work any more. and of course im having huge issues because of it.
i understand that this might be an edge case but what are the reasons this changed?

the affected code:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def initialize(self, request, response):    
        ns, path = get_namespace(os.environ)
        namespace_manager.set_namespace(ns)
        os.environ['namespace'] = ns

        # request.path reflects the incoming path

        path = os.environ.get('PATH_INFO')
        prefix = '/%s'%ns

        if ns and path.startswith(prefix):
            # the request.path has to be changed here...

            newpath = path[len(prefix):]
            # here i change the path_info in os.environ to the new 
            # path
            os.environ['PATH_INFO'] = newpath or '/'

        super(BaseHandler, self).initialize(request, response)

        # request.path and self.request.path here are still unchanged.
        # up to a few days ago here the path was reflecting the changes
```

Comment: Why are you chacning the path and not adding a new entity to headers?

Comment: i understand but i wanted to stay as close as possible to the default implementation to be able to use all self.request props and functions. but of course i would know how to work around the issue. still dont understand what changed in the last days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.environ` contains the CGI-style environment variables. WSGI applications such as webapp(2) may get their information from there (or not, depending on the container), but they're welcome - and even likely - to copy, not reference the original data. There's no reason to assume that manipulating `os.environ` will affect your WSGI app, and doing so is a bad idea for several reasons:

1. It breaks abstraction
2. It may not be threadsafe
3. It's just *nasty*

Instead, modify the request object directly (eg, by assigning to `request.path`), if you must - or better, store the relevant information in attributes on the request handler that your subhandlers can access.

Comment: your right. i tried to modify request.path directly but that of course didn't work. changing request.environ does the trick.

Comment: @aschmid00 Really? Modifying the request object _should_ work for most properties. What happened when you tried?

Comment: i get an `AttributeError: can't set attribute` because in `webob.Request` most of the properties i am accessing are `@property`s constructed from request.environ. while setting request.path directly does not work, setting `request.PATH_INFO`, `request.path_info` or `request.environ.PATH_INFO` does work as expected.